# Update state more efficiently in React native?

Tags: react-native, performance, state

I'm building a checklist app with multiple tabs. It works but when the list grows larger, it's not performing very snappy when I want to check 1 item for instance. I have the feeling this is because the entire state (consisting of all items in all tabs) is updated, when I just want to update 1 item. The tabs and items are generated dynamically (ie, at compile-time I don't know how many tabs there will be). Any idea how this could be done more efficiently?
This is the (stripped down) state provider:

```
export default class InpakStateProvider extends React.Component {

state = {projectName: " ", tabs: [{name: " ", items: [{checked: false, name: " "}]}]};   

DeleteItem = (categoryname: string, itemname: string) => {
    let stateTabs = this.state.tabs;

    var tab = stateTabs.find((tab) => tab.name == categoryname);
    if(tab){
        let index = tab.items.findIndex(el => el.name === itemname);
        tab.items.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.setState({projectName: this.state.projectName, tabs: stateTabs})      
};

CheckItem = (categoryname: string, itemname: string) => {
    var tab = this.state.tabs.find((tab) => tab.name == categoryname);
    if(tab){
        let index = tab.items.findIndex(el => el.name === itemname);
        tab.items[index] = { ...tab.items[index], checked: !tab.items[index].checked };
    }

    this.setState({projectName: this.state.projectName, tabs: this.state.tabs}); 
};

ClearChecks = () => {

    let stateTabs = this.state.tabs; 

    stateTabs.forEach((tab) => { 
        let tabItems = [...tab.items];
        tabItems.forEach((item) => item.checked = false);           
    });

    this.setState({projectName: this.state.projectName, tabs: stateTabs})       
}

render(){
    return (           
        <Context.Provider
            value={{
                projectName: this.state.projectName,
                tabs: this.state.tabs,                                
                DeleteItem: this.DeleteItem,
                CheckItem: this.CheckItem,
                ClearChecks: this.ClearChecks,             
            }}
        >
            {this.props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: In my opinion the state provider is not an issue here , but the list component. I assume you are using an flatlist and then you can have a look here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration how to optimize the performance. The PureComponent part is a crucial one.

Comment: @alvAro365 Thanks for the reply! I wasn't using a flatlist (just mapping my items). I've tried implementing a flatlist and used a pure component within the renderitem, but there is no improvement in performance for my app. I have about 10 tabs with 20 items each in my test project. Checking an item takes about a second. It's useable, but far from snappy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that all list components are being re-rendered upon updating the state. My advice is to move the state of `checked` inside of the list item component. Or if you don't want to do that, I advise you to read about React memoization.
If you go for the memoziation approach if you update the state, and the props of the list item didn't change, this will not re-render the unchanged components, it will only trigger the re-render for the components with the prop `checked` that has changed.
Here's the documentation for memoization if it helps: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html.

Also, on another note, always go for FlatLists instead of using map. You won't notice a big difference with a small dataset, but performance takes a big hit with mid-large datasets.